# Updating man-db to patch CVE-2015-1336 / CVE-2017-9525

Tags: apt

Am running Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS.

The default man-db packaged on Ubuntu 16.04 has a vulnerability (CVE-2015-1336 & CVE-2017-9525).

```
ii  man-db        2.7.5-1         amd64        on-line manual pager
```

> The daily mandb cleanup job in Man-db before 2.7.6.1-1 as packaged in Ubuntu and Debian allows local users with access to the man account to gain privileges via vectors involving insecure chown use.

apt-get update/upgrade won't update to a version that doesn't have this vulnerability.  How can I instruct Ubuntu to upgrade to a newer package?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up doing this:

```
sudo wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/m/man-db/man-db_2.7.6.1-2_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i man-db_2.7.6.1-2_amd64.deb
```

Seemed to work.